# How to replace button "powered by odoo" in web.login_layout odoo v16?

Tags: xml, odoo, data-files, odoo-16

I want to replace the button which is standard in odoo.
In earlier versions, for example in 14, it was possible to do it in the way that I show below.
However, it doesn't work now, and I still don't know how to properly remove the button and replace it with my fields.
I will be very grateful for your help.

**web.login_layout in odoo:**
[image: click to open image]

**My edit_weblayout.xml files:**

```
<odoo>
  <data>
    <template id="Login Layout" inherit_id="web.login_layout">
      <xpath expr="//div[@class='text-center small mt-4 pt-3 border-top']" position="replace">
        <field />
      </xpath>
    </template>
  </data>
</odoo>
```

**My manifest.py:**

```
    "data" : [
        "static/src/xml/edit_weblayout.xml",
    ],
```

But it doesn't work.

I described all the code that I used above, I will be grateful for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This work in Odoo-16.**

Through trial and error, I managed to remove "Powered by odoo" by replacing the block in which it is located.

But I hasten to note that this method also removes the `"Manage database"` button, if you suddenly need it, look for another way.
But I removed the ability to manage the database in `odoo.conf` and on the UI too, so this way is ok for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<odoo>
  <template id="login" inherit_id="web.login_layout" name="Custom Login" >
    <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('border-top')]" position="replace">
      <div id="remove_link">
      </div>
    </xpath>
  </template>
</odoo>
```

Comment: Database management page will still be available at `/web/database/manager` path, unless you don't disable it from `odoo.conf` too

Comment: I wrote about this and that I disabled it in the configuration, so it was no longer displayed for me, but if it is not disabled, only the link to it will disappear, but the control will still work.